Looking for a general overview of how harmonics on a torus would work
I'm a very early beginner to learning harmonics, and was wondering if someone answer some very general questions I have, since all of the articles I've found online immediately reference advanced mathematics I'm unfamiliar with.
Essentially I'm just wondering, generally, how harmonics and waves would behave on a simple torus (1, 2, or 3 dimensional). In, linear, one-dimensional visualizations of harmonics on say a rope, one alway sees the 'boundary conditions' as simply either ends of the rope (below).  My understanding is that these boundaries constrain the wave to have integer-multiples of half-wavelengths.  This constraint, as I understand it, is the precursor to the notion of quantization in quantum mechanics- quanta come in 'packets' just like the integer-valued waves.
I'm imagining that in a torus, one would join either end of the rope to form a loop.  This loop then pivots around a counterpoint, to form say a horn torus. Is the point-hole center of the torus somehow the 'boundary condition' of such a torus?  It's odd trying to visualize how a two-dimensional rope could have just one end point.
As is evident, I'm new to all of this but would just like a layman's overview of what's going on and further links to study.  All the articles I've found immediately go into advanced math I don't understand yet; for instance wiki states "Toroidal harmonics have many interesting properties..." but then references elliptic integrals, Laplace and partial differential equations etc that I'm unfamiliar with.  Is there a more layman's explanation of what these interesting properties may be?  thank you



(This may or may not be an answer to your question; I don't know anything about toroidal harmonics, and I can't tell what they have to do with any of the stuff I've discussed below.)
For simplicity let me only discuss two examples, the "flat circle" $S^1 = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and the "flat torus" $T^2 = \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$. Studying functions on these things corresponds to studying functions on $\mathbb{R}$ resp. $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are $1$-periodic (resp. periodic with respect to both $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$); explicitly, this means functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfying
$$f(x + 1) = f(x)$$
and functions $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfying
$$f(x + 1, y) = f(x, y + 1) = f(x, y).$$
This is sometimes called taking periodic boundary conditions. So rather than fixing the value of $f$ anywhere we can think of $f$ as a function on $[0, 1]$ resp. on $[0, 1]^2$ such that its values at the boundary are restricted to equal its values at other points on the boundary. Personally I prefer to think directly in terms of periodicity but this might be more intuitive depending on your taste.
We can define a harmonic (I am not sure if this is the right terminology) to be a function $f$ as above which satisfies the Helmholtz equation $\Delta f = \lambda f$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian (which is $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ in 1D and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ in 2D) and $\lambda$ is a scalar (which turns out to always be non-positive). This is an important example of an eigenvalue equation. The reason these functions deserve the name "harmonics" is that they produce standing wave solutions to the wave equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \Delta u$$
(where $u$ is now a function of one additional time variable $t$), namely the solutions $u = e^{i c \sqrt{-\lambda} t} f$ (remember that $\lambda$ is non-positive so $\sqrt{-\lambda}$ is real).
So, let's solve the eigenvalue equation $\Delta f = \lambda f$ for the Laplacian, where $f$ is periodic. In 1D this equation is just
$$\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} = \lambda f(x)$$
which can be solved using the usual characteristic equation method. We get that the solutions are spanned by $f(x) = e^{\pm \sqrt{\lambda} x}$. The constraint that $f(x + 1) = f(x)$ is satisfied iff $\sqrt{\lambda}$ is an integer multiple of $2 \pi i$, which means that the eigenvalues of the Laplacian in this case are
$$\lambda_k = - 4 \pi k^2, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
with corresponding eigenfunctions the waves $f_k = e^{2 \pi i k x}$, or if you prefer the waves $\cos 2 \pi k x, \sin 2 \pi k x$, either way is fine. If you've ever solved the wave equation on an interval this should look pretty familiar, it's the same idea.
Now let's do 2D. We want to solve
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = \lambda f(x, y)$$
where $f$ is periodic in both $x$ and $y$. We'll do it using separation of variables, guessing solutions of the form
$$f_{a, b}(x, y) = e^{2 \pi iax} e^{2 \pi iby}$$
since if $a$ and $b$ are integers these functions have the required periodicity. Plugging in this guess (or ansatz) we get
$$\Delta f_{a, b} = - 4 \pi^2 (a^2 + b^2) f_{a, b}$$
So the $f_{a, b}$ are in fact eigenfunctions. The theory of Fourier series can be used to show that every eigenfunction has this form, so the eigenvalues of the Laplacian in this case are
$$\lambda_{a, b} = - 4 \pi^2 (a^2 + b^2), a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$$
with corresponding eigenfunctions the waves $f_{a, b}$. Plotting these (or rather, the corresponding sines and cosines) gets you some interesting pictures; for example here's a plot of $\cos (4 \pi x + 6 \pi y)$ from WolframAlpha:
                                              
The eigenvalues have interesting multiplicities now, governed by the number of ways to write a number as the sum of two squares, which has a surprisingly interesting number-theoretic answer due to Jacobi. This is a first hint of the rich theory of theta functions.
Maybe you can guess now what happens in higher dimensions!

 These arguments generalize to flat tori, which have the form $\mathbb{R}^n/L$ where $L$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The eigenvalues in this case turn out to be given (up to that pesky factor of $- 4 \pi^2$) by the norms in the vectors in the dual lattice. Milnor famously used this construction for $n = 16$ to produce an example of two isospectral Riemannian manifolds (meaning their Laplacians have the same eigenvalues) which are not isometric; this was a partial answer to the question "can you hear the shape of a drum?".

